# JFileChooser - multiple file filters?

Tags: java, file, save, jfilechooser

I have a question about the JFileChooser in Swing. I'm trying to get multiple file extensions in the drop-down box, but have no idea how to do it.

There is the method

```
extFilter = FileNameExtensionFilter(description, extensions);
```

that I can then use by writing

```
fileChooser.setFileFilter(extFilter);
```

however, as you can see, this only supports one option in the drop-down list. How do I add more?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want the `addChoosableFileFilter` method.  Read the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

You can simply create a filter that subclasses `FileFilter` and call the method I outlined above with that filter as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you have already solved this to your satisfaction, but I came across this [link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/A_351-Custom-File-Filtering-Using-Java-File-Choosers.html) at the same time I came across your question. In particular, look at section 3 for a way to generate multiple filters easily.

Comment: even tough this answer has more than 3 years was surprisingly useful, having a class extending the filechooser class to add your own behavior it's way useful!

Answer (score 1):

use

```java
filter.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(description, extensions));
```

as many as the number of your extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked long back, but one can take the following steps to define multiple extensions:

`JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(); jfc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Select XSL Files","xsl","xslt"));`