# Dynamic file extension filtration using jfilechooser java

Tags: java, string, io, jfilechooser, filefilter

I am using  `FileNameExtensionFilter` function to filter file names in `jfilechooser` 
but the input parameter for extension is of String type.
I want to read all the extensions from a text file.
filter is in the constructor and I'm developing a notepad kind of application in Netbeans form.
solve this or give some better solution to this problem and i only want to use `jfilechooser` functionality  to select and filter files

Thanks in advance

Here is code.

```
///////////////FILE FILTER
String str= ""txt","abc","xyz","wxy"; //all extensions from TXTfile

public MainFrame(){
    initComponents();
    fileChooser=new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXTFILES",str,"text");
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
}

////////////////////////  FILE READER
String readFile() throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ext.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
       line = br.readLine();
    }
    return sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: you might looking for this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450223/jfilechooser-multiple-file-filters

Comment: I know the simple implementation by just giving the extension i want to read all values from the txt file.

i am unable to assign the output from file to the filenamefilter.

Comment: so you are looking for passing an array of extensions rather single extension?

Comment: yes but i want to populate this array from a textfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JLS,`FileNameExtensionFilter` method  takes  "String... extensions",  so you what i suggest modficiations in your code is,

```
// all extensions from TXTfile
String[] extensions= {"txt","abc","xyz","wxy"}; 

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXTFILES",extensions);
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " 
+fileChooser.getName(new File("ext.txt")));//or you can use getSelectedFile() that  user has choosen.
    }
```

Comment: yes
in the same way i want to populate this string from a text file

Comment: from a text file means what?which file? is it choosen file?

Comment: i mean to say IO operation to retrieve whole file in a String array like..... String[] extensions= readFile.read("extensions.txt"); .... .

I am righting all extensions to a TEXT file and want them in the string array to use in filenamefilter function .

Comment: Txt file formate is..
...  one extension per line ...
Txt 
png 
..etc